# Prevent creating an empty line at the end of flat file destination

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, flatfiledestination

When inserting data into a flat file destination, an empty line is shown at the end. How can i remove it?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve]. Please make the effort to show and explain your problem in textual form here and show your own attempts to do it yourself.

Comment: line cannot be removed because the last row delimiter

Answer (score 0):

This line cannot be removed because the last line (before this line) need to ends with a row delimiter which is by default a carridge return + line feed `CrLf`. This causes to show this line.

So you have to write a script after inserting data is finish if this procedure is needed.